# What's the name of the font used in Cape Charles?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

What is the name of this font and it's family ?[image]

Comment: I'd isolate each letter with about 10px of space and try it at [WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/). It has a hard time with scripts if you don't disconnect the letters.

Comment: I tried that. It didn't match it. And identifont came up with Coronet!

Comment: neither i found in whatfontis.com and www.whatfontis.com

Comment: Judging by the sloppiness of the drawing, it's probably a freebie from some random place on the web. If you aren't locked to it exactly, [dig through MyFonts' scripts](http://www.myfonts.com/search/tag%3AScript/fonts/?testdrive=seed%3D25%26size%3D72%26text%3DCape%2520Charles%26fg%3D000000%26bg%3Dffffff%26src%3Dcustom%26goodies%3Dot.liga%26browser%255B%255D) for a better substitute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's Mission Script designed by James T. Edmondson for LostType:

http://www.losttype.com/font/?name=mission_script